# Swift, stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString and replace array

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, replace, swift

I need to replace numeric characters. I mean I want to replace english char with bengali chat within a string. Let say, I've two arrays,

`var enDigits = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]` and 
`var bnDigits = ["১", "২", "৩", "৪", "৫", "৬", "৭", "৮", "৯", "০"]`.

I'm in new in iOS & definitely in swift. In PHP, `str_replace()` can do that easily. However, I search and found `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString` for swift but cannot figure out if that can work with array. I need your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty specific answer, but if you're just looking to replace character for character, you could use the `map` function on your source string, like this:

```
let enDigits: [Character] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
let bnDigits: [Character] = ["১", "২", "৩", "৪", "৫", "৬", "৭", "৮", "৯", "০"]

let enString = "Jenny's number is 867-5309"
let bnString = String(map(enString, { ch in
    if let index = find(enDigits, ch) {
        return bnDigits[index]
    }
    return ch
}))
// Jenny's number is ৮৬৭-৫৩০৯
```

Comment: Excellent. Worked like charm :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're actually looking to convert into Bengali numerals, Cocoa provides an API for doing [ICU transforms](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general):

```
var string = "Jenny's number is 867-5309"
let transform = "[:Number:]; Any-Latin; Latin-Bengali"

let cfstr = NSMutableString(string: String(string)) as CFMutableString
var range = CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(cfstr))
CFStringTransform(cfstr, &range, ((transform as NSString) as CFString), 0)

println(cfstr) // Jenny's number is ৮৬৭-৫৩০৯
```

Comment: Nice! Hey, I remember reading a [great article about `CFStringTransform`](http://nshipster.com/cfstringtransform/) a while back...